# Running espresso after proguarding app but not test

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-proguard

I enabled:

```
testBuildType "release"
```

to run the espresso-tests after proguard - but I get a problem with mockito then. Can I disable proguard for the test-code? Or anyone sees a reason why even when I add this to my proguard-config:

```
-dontwarn org.mockito.**
-dontwarn sun.reflect.**
-dontwarn android.test.**
```

it still fails with:

```
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanGenerator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanGenerator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanGenerator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanGenerator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanGenerator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter$1: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter$1: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter$1: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter$3: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter$3: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.BeanMapEmitter$3: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.beans.ImmutableBean$Generator: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.Task
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.Task
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.tools.ant.Project getProject()' in program class org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find referenced class org.apache.tools.ant.Project
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractTransformTask: can't find referenced method 'void log(java.lang.String,int)' in program class org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractTransformTask
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractTransformTask: can't find referenced method 'void log(java.lang.String)' in program class org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractTransformTask
```

--

for the record here the more of the warnings:

```
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find superclass or interface org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.JMock1Adapter: can't find superclass or interface org.jmock.core.Constraint
Warning: org.mockito.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.tools.ant.Task
Warning: library class android.test.AndroidTestCase extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase
Warning: library class android.test.AndroidTestRunner extends or implements program class junit.runner.BaseTestRunner
Warning: library class android.test.InstrumentationTestCase extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase
Warning: library class android.test.InstrumentationTestSuite extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestSuite
Warning: library class android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64$Cell: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64$Cell: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.cache.Striped64$Cell: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:     Warning: android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Instrumentation$ActivityResult execStartActivity(android.content.Context,android.os.IBinder,android.os.IBinder,android.app.Activity,android.content.Intent,int)' in program class android.support.test.internal.runner.hidden.ExposedInstrumentationApi
Warning: android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Instrumentation$ActivityResult execStartActivity(android.content.Context,android.os.IBinder,android.os.IBinder,android.app.Activity,android.content.Intent,int,android.os.Bundle)' in program class android.support.test.internal.runner.hidden.ExposedInstrumentationApi
Warning: android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Instrumentation$ActivityResult execStartActivity(android.content.Context,android.os.IBinder,android.os.IBinder,android.app.Fragment,android.content.Intent,int,android.os.Bundle)' in program class android.support.test.internal.runner.hidden.ExposedInstrumentationApi
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.JavaBeanDescriptor: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.JavaBeanDescriptor: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.JavaBeanDescriptor: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.JavaBeanDescriptor: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.PropertySupport: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.PropertySupport: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter$1: can't find referenced class org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter$1: can't find referenced class org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter$1: can't find referenced class org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.Introspection: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.Introspection: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.Introspection: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.Introspection: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.Introspection: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.Introspection: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.Introspection: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.Introspection: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.Introspection: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.Introspection: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.Introspection: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.xml.XmlStringPrettyFormatter: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.xml.XmlStringPrettyFormatter: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.xml.XmlStringPrettyFormatter: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: org.assertj.core.util.xml.XmlStringPrettyFormatter: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: org.hamcrest.JMock1Matchers: can't find referenced class org.jmock.core.Constraint
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue$2: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.PropertyUtil: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs$PropertyMatcher: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs$PropertyMatcher: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs$PropertyMatcher: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs$PropertyMatcher: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs$PropertyMatcher: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find referenced class org.easymock.EasyMock
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find referenced class org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find referenced class org.easymock.EasyMock
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find referenced class org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find referenced class org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.JMock1Adapter: can't find referenced class org.jmock.core.Constraint
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.JMock1Adapter: can't find referenced class org.jmock.core.Constraint
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.JMock1Adapter: can't find referenced class org.jmock.core.Constraint
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
Warning: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
Warning: org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning: org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean
Warning: org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
Warning: org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean
Warning: org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator: can't find referenced class sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory
Warning: org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator: can't find referenced class sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory
Warning: org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator: can't find referenced class sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory
Warning: org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator: can't find referenced class sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory
Warning: org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactorySerializationInstantiator: can't find referenced class sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory
Warning: org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactorySerializationInstantiator: can't find referenced class sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory
Warning: org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactorySerializationInstantiator: can't find referenced class sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory
Warning: org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactorySerializationInstantiator: can't find referenced class sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory
```

Ideally I want to disable proguarding the test-code - but proguarding the app-apk is important to me as this tests the proguard-config/result

Comment: Can you put your gradle file, especially the dependencies part, and your proguard file ? It seems that your strip the testing library off because the proguard file doesn't keep them.

Comment: agreed that gradle and proguard files will be helpful... are you applying the mapping from proguarding the app to the test apk?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom proguard file applied to your debug build, you may want to also apply it to the test build:

```
        testProguardFile 'proguard-rules-test.pro'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid proguard warnings related to [com.square](https://github.com/square/okhttp) add these rules to your proguard file:

```
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-dontnote
```